# How to align widgets in a GridView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, gridview, alignment

I want to **align** the contents of a GridView item to the center (*both vertically and horizontally*) **without changing the size of the widget**.

This code creates a `GridView` with an item in it, it has a default top-center alignment and the size is a default square.

```
GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 3, 
  children: [
    Container(
      // alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text("Top text"),
            Text("Bottom text"),
          ],
        ),
        onPressed: (){}
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

And it looks like this:[image: Without alignment]

When I uncomment the alignment, it doesn't align the items correctly and the size of the item changes, I don't want neither of them.

[image: With alignment]

Note that I need multiple `Widget`s in that `GridView` item, so I can't remove the `Column` (but maybe I can replace it?).

Comment: Just add MainAxisAlignment.center to the Column widget to align all its contents to the center like this >> Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children:[.......]);

Comment: @bluenile Thanks, with your code the `Widget` is aligned to the center, just as I wanted. Although its **size still changed**, do you have any idea to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any size change after adding mainAxisAlignment to the Column. Please run the code below :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      children: [
        Container(
          // alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: RaisedButton(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text("Top text"),
                  Text("Bottom text"),
                ],
              ),
              onPressed: () {}),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```